# uv_ip4_name always getting 127.0.0.1

Tags: c++, nginx, libuv

This is my current code:

```cpp
        struct sockaddr_storage addr;
        
        int addr_len = sizeof(addr);
        uv_tcp_getpeername(client, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &addr_len);
        
        char buf[128];
        if(uv_ip4_name((struct sockaddr_in*) &addr, buf, sizeof buf) != 0) buf[0] = '\0';
```

This worked without nginx, but now I'm using ngnix for ssl. This is part of my config:

```
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2828;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

And this still isn't having ANY effect on what `buf` is (`buf` is the ip). Its always 127.0.0.1

Comment: is nginx running locally as a peer process to call your code? the nginx is accepting the socket - so you'd have to parse the http request headers.

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't get what you mean by "is nginx running locally as a peer process to call your code? ", sorry

Comment: Describe how nginx calls your code

Comment: @DanielA.White If you mean by the config file its: `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

Comment: since you are doing a proxy pass to local host, the source socket isn’t used. You have to use the http headers that you set

Comment: @DanielA.White How exactly would I do that?

Comment: No idea. That’s up to your code

Comment: @DanielA.White The problem is I can't find anything anywhere for that, and it makes things very difficult

Comment: What web server is your code running? Where is it parsing headers?

Comment: @DanielA.White My server is using `libuv` to run a `websocket` server on port `2828`